# webapi deserialize JSON request with datetime in controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Option 1:
If I deserialize my JSON request manually, I get a correct result:

```
[Route("search")]
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<ErrorLogDto> Search(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    string res = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    LogSearchDto dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res, typeof(LogSearchDto)) as LogSearchDto;
    //dto = not null
```

Option 2: If I use this, I always get NULL value for dto:

```
[Route("search")]
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<ErrorLogDto> Search([FromBody]LogSearchDto dto)
{
// dto = null!
```

I am out of ideas how to debug this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search, I solved the problem by **removing** following lines from Global.asax.cs:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
```